# Any way to temporarily attach/pin a part of a rigged and animated character to a STATIC object?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

so I'm pretty new to Blender in general and completely new to animation. I'm playing around with an animation of King Kong climbing a building, from the perspective of being inside looking out the window. I have Kong rigged and animated with a Mixamo mocap animation of someone climbing.

The problem I'm having is that his hands and feet are sliding around all over the place. Is there any way of temporarily pinning his hand to a certain spot on the static building object (or just a specific point in space) so that the rest of his body pivots around that, then un-pinning it so he can raise his hand to the next spot, while pinning the other hand in place. Does that make sense?
I know I could do it by literally hand animating the entire thing, but I was hoping there was an easier way. Apologies if this is a really stupid and simple question.

Thanks a lot!

[image: Kong Climbing]

Answer (score 1):

you can give a *Child Of* constraint to the hand controller, with for example an empty as *Target*, then move the empty when the character is supposed to move his hand from a location to another:

[image]